# JS Model Detailed Errors

Tags: magnolia

I am using a JavaScript model to call a Java class and return results from a database.
When there is an error eg. DB server down, I can see the error details in the tomcat output screen on windows but the errors are not stored in Catalina.out or Magnolia-debug log files.

On linux where tomcat runs as a service, there is no output screen so I cannot see the exact error. I can only see invalid reference exception or cannot instantiate JS model.

How / where is it possible to see the exact errors encountered by the model? eg. could not establish DB connection, expired passowrd or whatever detailed error there is?

Comment: Can you add example of exception and message that is printed to the console but missing from the log file? It could have many causes, eg issue with logs after log rotation (known problem of log4j), printing exception from JS instead of from java, the java code not logging it correctly, etc. Also check that your model follows https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions and encapsulates errors properly and prints them out to logs correctly.

Comment: @Jan You are right, I was printing the errors on the screen, not logging them properly. Thanks. If you wish, you can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have many causes, eg issue with logs after log rotation (known problem of log4j), printing exception from JS instead of from java, the java code not logging it correctly, etc.
Also check that your model follows wiki.openjdk.org/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions and encapsulates errors properly and prints them out to logs correctly.